# Wireless device not showing up

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, usb, kali-linux

So I have a Product: VNT USB-802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter.
I connected it to my computer today after not having it connected for awhile and it suddenly does not show up as a network adapter.
I checked to see that it does recognize it via the lsusb commands, shows up seems to be working there but still nothing.
Dmesg shows a lot of problems but the google-fu is not returning anything of use. Says to update my kernel from 3, but I'm on 4.
Ideas?

> uname -r

```
4.0.0-kali1-amd64
```

> dmesg

```
[ 1636.272575] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1636.472153] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=160a, idProduct=3184
[ 1636.472160] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1636.472164] usb 3-1: Product: VNT USB-802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter
[ 1636.472167] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: VIA Networking Technologies, Inc.
[ 1637.503301] vt6656_stage: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[ 1637.503540] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_hw
[ 1637.503545] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_hw (err -22)
[ 1637.503581] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_tkip_p2k
[ 1637.503584] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_tkip_p2k (err -22)
[ 1637.503595] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_register_hw
[ 1637.503598] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_register_hw (err -22)
[ 1637.503609] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_hdrlen_from_skb
[ 1637.503612] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_hdrlen_from_skb (err -22)
[ 1637.503627] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_key_tx_seq
[ 1637.503630] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_key_tx_seq (err -22)
[ 1637.503636] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_tx_status_irqsafe
[ 1637.503639] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_tx_status_irqsafe (err -22)
[ 1637.503783] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queues
[ 1637.503786] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queues (err -22)
[ 1637.503792] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_txskb
[ 1637.503794] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_txskb (err -22)
[ 1637.503802] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw_nm
[ 1637.503805] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw_nm (err -22)
[ 1637.503840] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_queues
[ 1637.503843] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queues (err -22)
[ 1637.503856] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw
[ 1637.503858] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw (err -22)
[ 1637.503887] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
[ 1637.503889] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err -22)
[ 1637.503900] vt6656_stage: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rx_irqsafe
[ 1637.503902] vt6656_stage: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rx_irqsafe (err -22)
```

> lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 160a:3184 VIA Technologies, Inc. VIA VNT-6656 [WiFi 802.11b/g USB Dongle]
```

> modinfo vt6656_stage

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.0.0-kali1-amd64/kernel/drivers/staging/vt6656/vt6656_stage.ko
description:    VIA Networking Wireless LAN USB Driver
license:        GPL
author:         VIA Networking Technologies, Inc., <lyndonchen@vntek.com.tw>
firmware:       vntwusb.fw
alias:          usb:v160Ap3184d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        mac80211,usbcore,cfg80211
staging:        Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.0.0-kali1-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           rx_buffers:Number of receive usb rx buffers (int)
parm:           tx_buffers:Number of receive usb tx buffers (int)
```